# Razor / ASP.NET MVC Core 7: How to return the edited grid data from all paginations to the controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I have editable table in UI that extends up to multiple paginations. I am using datatables.net library display this table along with pagination.

https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap5.html

After user edits the data in the grid, I need to return the data of all cells back to the controller for which I use the below jQuery / AJAX code. But it actually returns only that page's data alone back. How can I return data from all paginations to action method in controller.

```
 var myTableArray = [];
        $('#table1').each(function () {
            var tds = $(this).find('td');
            //console.log('tds',tds);
            for(i=0; i<tds.length; i++) {
                 myTableArray.push(tds[i].textContent);
            }
        });
        console.log('myTableArray', myTableArray);
        
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Controller/Action',
            data: myTableArray,
        });
```

Comment: Use must use the datatables api, don't read the values from the HTML (your `$("#table1").find("td")`) as the HTML only includes the current page.

Comment: @freedomn-m we tried that but edited or changed data in grid is not coming in that

Comment: Are you changing the data *in the datatable* (ie via the API) or are you changing the properties of the HTML?   Given that you're reading the HTML (in provided code) you're probably changing HTML as well, so it's not being reflected in the api data, so being *lost* when you change page etc.